# Python Not Correctly Calculating Unix from Datetime

Tags: python, datetime, unix

Looking for help with this conversion.
month day year hours minutes seconds to UNIX
Code is running, but we are getting incorrect conversions.
Main Column is our DateTime column.

## Imports

```
import os
import pathlib
import chardet
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime
from datetime import timezone
```

## Conversion to Time Unix

```
print('[Time Unix] Generating time unix from "' + main_column + '" column...')
time_unix = []
format = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'
for col_val in final[main_column]:
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(col_val, format)
    unix_time = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
    time_unix.append(int(unix_time))

final['Time Unix'] = pd.Series(time_unix)

# Sort based on the mentioned column name
print('[sorting] Sorting rows based on the "' + main_column + '" column...')
final.sort_values(ascending=True, inplace=True, by=['Time Unix'])
```

but... look at the result... completely differente DateTime giving the same unix values.

## DateTime           |   Unix

```
2/24/2019 2:17:46 PM    1551017867
2/24/2019 9:07:19 PM    1551017867
2/24/2019 5:40:39 PM    1551017867
2/24/2019 2:17:47 PM    1551017868
2/24/2019 9:07:20 PM    1551017868
2/24/2019 5:40:40 PM    1551017868
2/24/2019 2:17:48 PM    1551017869
2/24/2019 9:07:21 PM    1551017869
2/24/2019 5:40:41 PM    1551017869
```

I cannot see any pattern in this error.
Hoping for help with formatting of this conversion.
Thanks

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mre] including some sample data, without the unused imports.

Comment: Scratch that, looking at Araldo's answer, you *need* to provide an MRE

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import timezone

time_unix = []
final = pd.DataFrame({'main_column': ['2/24/2019 2:17:46 PM',
                                    '2/24/2019 9:07:19 PM',
                                    '2/24/2019 5:40:41 PM']})

format = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'
for col_val in final['main_column']:
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(col_val, format)
    unix_time = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
    time_unix.append(int(unix_time))

final['Time Unix'] = pd.Series(time_unix)
final.sort_values(ascending=True, inplace=True, by=['Time Unix'])
print(final)
```

Output:

```
            main_column   Time Unix
0  2/24/2019 2:17:46 PM  1551017866
2  2/24/2019 5:40:41 PM  1551030041
1  2/24/2019 9:07:19 PM  1551042439
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the error lied else where as we were joining several CSVs together.
Thanks for taking the time to confirm the code was correct.